# An ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError occurred in sessions#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, postman, ruby-on-rails-6, parse-error

I have a production Rails 6 application.  I get notified when an error occurs on the site.  We currently have someone that I suspect is trying to be nefarious which has caused multiple ParseErrors to different end points, typically endpoints set up using devise. I can see that they are taking parameters from different areas of the site in addition to adding their own and trying to send a request:

```
An ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError occurred in passwords#create:

822: unexpected token at 'utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=yay0c3PqNyV5PE6u613nCzdl%2BEPZClNiZF1hcTiPrXbwsqUJyJ9XWdo3K9v2YzjQeV63r8IkpMwRysvKGlkZ0w%3D%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=BrennaCollelo66%40aol.com&commit=Send+me+reset+password+instructions'

* URL        : https://myurl.com/users/password
* HTTP Method: POST
* IP address : 113.163.57.58
* Parameters : {}
```

I've used Postman to try to replicate the error:

[image: postmanrequest]

But when I try I always get a 200 response.  Any ideas on what I can do to replicate the error or prevent them from making the request?

Comment: If there is an identifyable pattern to the malicous requests (like the typical Wordpress exploit bots) you can block the requests either on the application server layer (NGinx, Apache, etc) or if thats not possible on the Rack middleware layer with [Rack::Attack](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack).

Answer (score 0):

Many clients will scrub or escape illegal characters.  You must post the raw json in body and set the content type to reproduce the error.

In rspec

```rb
  it "decodes JSON with tabs" do

    # To post requests with tabs in params
    #  * use json text instead of params hash
    #  * add Content-Type to headers
    # Otherwise params will be cleaned and
    # you can't test ability to handle unclean params

    json_text = "{\"asset\":{\"external_id\":\"ABCD\t\"}}"
    headers['Conten-Type'] = 'application/json'

    post "/api/assets.json", params: json_text, headers: headers
    expect(response.status).to eq(201)
  end
```

In Postman.  In this example the password has a 'tab' character in it.  Normally this tab would be escaped by clients.

[image]

[image]